# PHP 7.1.7 - A non-numeric value encountered - even though already checked is_numeric

Tags: operators, php-7.1

I've getting this non-numeric error when trying to add even though I've already checked with is_numeric. I've tried converting the $value with number_format, (float), (int). Nothing seems to work. The values are present and number from a posted multiple field.

```
    $amount = 0;
    $transaction_amount = isset($_POST['TransactionCharge']['amount']) ? $_POST['TransactionCharge']['amount']: array();
    foreach($transaction_amount as $value) {
       if ( is_numeric($value) ) {
          $amount += number_format($value,2);
       }
    }
```

Interesting note:

```
    $amount = array_sum($transaction_amount);
```

seems to work in lieu of iterating array. Is that the only way to do this in 7.1?

Comment: What is the exact value and type of the variable?

Comment: $transaction_amount is an array of posted form field input's w/ numeric values (E.g. 1, 2, 3).

Comment: So they’re strings whereas `number_format` expects a float?

Comment: Try dumping the output of the number_format call. Chances are you are getting something like `1,234.56` back (with a thousands separator), which is not numeric and will be interpreted as `1` (part before `,`).

Comment: so strange since it passes is_numeric and i get the same error whether using number_format or not when applying the addition operator. The values I'm testing with is literally (1) (2) (3) without commas and it still fails. I've tried converting to float and same result.  "array_sum" seems to work well (and is simpler) so will chalk it up to a "better way" to add an array and call it quits for now. should it come up again will come back to it. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply used array_sum method to implement.